# How to auto commit svn without need to click on OK button

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Am using the below batch command to auto commit the changes into SVN.But I need to click on OK button to commit the changes.Is there any way to auto commit without manual intervention? Please let me know.

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe"  /command:commit /path:"D:\SvnCheckOut" /url:"svn://sample project"  /closeonend:3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong tool. You should use `svn.exe` client.

`TortoiseProc.exe` is designed for GUI automation. [Read the docs](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), please:

> Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide
>   shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user
>   input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you
>   should use the official Subversion command line client instead.

Comment: ok.But am not finding svn.exe under this path " C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" .Please suggest if we can change any svn settings

Comment: @Rahul update TortoiseSVN to a modern version 1.9. TortoiseSVN comes with standard SVN command-line tools since version 1.7 AFAIR. Note that you can always grab the latest command-line tools from https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/

Comment: is that version licensed?Please let me know.

Comment: @Rahul what do you mean by "licensed"?